# Make selected colours brighter in Blender

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

The problem: I am working with a set of objects in Blender with per-vertex colours. Each object has only two distinct colours. For all objects in a selection, I am choosing only the brighter of those two colours, and increasing its brightness by 10%.

Language: Python 3.7

About me: I am new to coding in Python, having read through a few tutorials and looked at some example code that other Blender users have created. I have coded extensively in R, but am completely self-taught, so who knows what bad habits I have picked up.

Feedback requested: any, but in particular if there are any big efficiency gains that I can make, given that I am working with meshes that have large numbers of vertices.

The code:

```
from bpy import context

# Iterate over all selected objects
selection = context.selected_objects

for object in selection:

    # Get the colour data for the selected object
    v_col = object.data.vertex_colors[0]
    color = list(v_col.data[0].color)

    # Find the colour of the brighter segment
    all_colours = list()
    for data in v_col.data:
        all_colours.append(list(data.color))
        
    segY = max(all_colours)

    # Assign new colour values to this segment
    new_colour = [min(x*1.1, 1) for x in segY]
    for data in v_col.data:
        if list(data.color) == segY:
            data.color = new_colour
```